# Bitmasks vs if..then in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I am working on an app that contains quite a lot of flags checks in different places, like

```
if (a && b && c) { func1() } 
else if (a && !b && c) { func2() }
else if (!a && b && !c) { func3() }
...
```

Sometimes it happens that there can be 10 checks in one sequence.

This looks quite bulky when there are more than 3 checks to me.
I read about bitwise operations and [bitmasks technique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) which I think can give me an elegant solution.

Though, I wonder if it's a good practice to use these practices in a real-world project where programmers of different level work. Trying not to be a smartass, but to make the code more elegant though easily readable, should I keep using `if...else` or should I start using bitwise operations?

Comment: imho, your team mates should learn bitwise operations. That said, we cant say that it's actually a good option since you dont provide a real world example :-|

Comment: I'd say it would depend on how exposed are the bit masks. Given a mask for `a, b, c` would your team mates need to write `mask = mask ^ 2` to set `b` to false, or would you provide some abstraction like `set_param( name, value )` and handle the XORing under the hood? How would you make sure that everyone keeps track of the order of ten parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think bitwise is a better solution.

```
const ACTIONS = {
  0: func0,
  1: func1,
  2: func2,
  3: func3,
  4: func4
  // ...
}

ACTIONS[a | b | c]()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find it clearer to use a `switch` block with *binary literals* as the case labels:

```
switch (foo){
case 0b111: /*corresponds to true-like a, b, and c*/
    func1();
    break;
case 0b101: /*corresponds to true-like a and c*/
    func2();
    break;
```

etc., where `foo` is an appropriate function of `a`, `b`, and `c`, generated perhaps using something like `4 * a + 2 * b + c`.

Comment: Keep in mind that the amount of cases is limited by the size of an integer. For example, in some cases you wont be able to test more than 32 values.

Comment: Don't you mean 32 separate flags? That gives you 2 to the 32nd power number of possible cases!

Comment: I mean 32 "parameters", sorry :-)